# Python changing function definition in loop?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible to do the following: If a function takes a function as argument, can I make it so that the argument of the inner function can be changed in a loop?

I have a function that takes any function f and integrates it over a, b. The problem is if I in a loop want to integrate cos(1* x) and then cos(2*x) ....cos(N*x) I don't know how to make my first function understand that when I say integrate(f(i),a,b) I don't mean integrate cos(1) or cos(2) BUT cos(1*x) or cos(2*x) and so on.

Eg:

```
def integrate(f,a,b):
 h = float(b-a)/10;
 I = 0;
 for i in range(10):
   I+= f(h*i);   <----(1)
return I;

A = zeros(N);
for k in range(N):
  A[k] = integrate(cos(k), a,b)   <-----(2)
```

What I want is for cos(k) in (2) to be called such that in (1) it becomes f(k * h * i), does this make sense to you? I want to change the parameter of (1) by changing (2). I need this for a fourier series function I am doing. The way it currently works is that instead of calling cos() with (k * h* i) inside the paranthesis it will just call cos(k).

Comment: But you're _not_ passing a function to `integrate`, you're passing the value returned by `cos(k)`.

Comment: Yes exactly my problem, I want to pass the function cos(k * ) such that when it passes into integrate instead of f(h*i) it is now f(k*h*i).

Comment: There is an ugly way I can solve the problem, I just have to pass an evaluated function to integrate instead of a function to be integrated over a,b with N points. But this is ugly..and I don't want to hand in ugly code, the assignment doesn't care how I do it I just can't sleep. There must be a finer way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *not* passing a function to `integrate`, you're passing the value returned by `cos(k)`. If I understand your goal correctly, this should be fixable by passing a [lambda (an anonymous function)](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
def integrate(f, a, b):
    h = float(b-a)/10
    I = 0;
    for i in range(10):
        I += f(h*i)

    return I

A = zeros(N)
for k in range(N):
    A[k] = integrate(lambda x: cos(k*x), a, b)
```

If that's hard to read, you can accomplish an equivalent end using a "normal" `def`d function which closes over `k`:

```
A = zeros(N)
for k in range(N):
    def callback(x):
        return k*x

    A[k] = integrate(callback, a, b)
```

(code not tested)

Comment: This worked and already implemented, though partial looks very neat.
Now to find a good benchmarking tool to see if partial is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools

def cos_(k, x):
    return cos(k * x)

#...
A[k] = integrate(functools.partial(cos_, k), a, b)
```

Also, Python doesn't require semicolons.